# setTimeout update google map v3 markers

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Somebody can help me? I'm trying to realize a map that will contain the data of my weather stations.
I wish to use google map in order to have a good view, but I can't understand why my code loads the markers correctly but do not update them:

```
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 8,
            maxZoom: 12, 
            minZoom: 4, 
            streetViewControl: false,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.5, 14),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
            mapOptions);
    }

    function loadMarker() {
        <?php
            $query3 = mysql_query("SELECT id,coordinate FROM stazioni WHERE visibilemappa = 1",$conn); 
            while($riga_c=mysql_fetch_array($query3)) { 
                if ($riga_c['coordinate']!="") {
                    echo "var my".$riga_c['id']." = new google.maps.LatLng(".$riga_c['coordinate'].");
                                ";
                }
            }

            $query3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stazioni WHERE visibilemappa = 1",$conn); 
            while($riga_c=mysql_fetch_array($query3)) { 
                if ($riga_c['coordinate']!="") echo   "var marker".$riga_c['id']." = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: my".$riga_c['id'].",
                            map: map,
                        icon: 'genera_scritta.php?testo=".str_replace("<br>"," - ",$riga_c['temperatura'])."',
                            title: '".str_replace("<br>"," - ",$riga_c['localita'])." ".date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A')."'
                        });
                        ";

            }
        ?>
    }

    setTimeout(function() {  loadMarker(); }, 3000);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', loadMarker);
```

I use Chrome. Thank's at all!!

Comment: Don't you need to use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`?

Comment: On internet I read sometime to use setInterval and other times to use setTimeout.
Honestly, I'm a bit confused...

Comment: So you have two calls to `loadMarker`, you should only need one.

Comment: I have to use 'google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', loadMarker);' because without it, on start the page do not loads the markers.

Comment: ok, so in that case get rid of the call after the 3 second interval

Comment: that was my try to update the markers on run time...

Comment: Hang on, are you expecting the function to re-query the DB after 3 seconds to get updated weather data?  If so that concept is completely wrong, you're mixing up server-side and client-side code.  And you should then use an AJAX request each time instead to get the latest server-side data every time.

Comment: yes, my goal wish be an updating map with new weather values.

I'll try to migrate on Ajax...

Answer (score 0):

1) You have a variable scope problem. You are using php to output var inside one function that will not be seen by the other function.

2) On a side note, I would say it is a better practice to use ajax to get the id's, instead of having php queries embedded. That way, you can do error handling.

Comment: uhm, I read many examples how to refresh markers, and I found some using ajax and others no. I was trying to avoid ajax because I don't know it!

Answer (score 0):

You run what's essentially two very similar queries, and loop over each one.  Instead you could achieve all you want with one query and one loop.  Something like:

```
function loadMarker() {
     <?php
         $query3 = mysql_query("SELECT id,coordinate,temperatura FROM stazioni WHERE visibilemappa = 1",$conn); 
         while($riga_c=mysql_fetch_array($query3)) { 
             if ($riga_c['coordinate']!="") {
                 echo   "var marker".$riga_c['id']." = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: new google.maps.LatLng(".$riga_c['coordinate']."),
                            map: map,
                            icon: 'genera_scritta.php?testo=".str_replace("<br>"," - ",$riga_c['temperatura'])."',
                            title: '".str_replace("<br>"," - ",$riga_c['localita'])." ".date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A')."'
                        });
                  ";
              }
          }
      ?>
}
```